# JavaFX chessboard build, set gridpane cell color

Tags: java, javafx

I made this 2d array. I think you gonna understand it.

```
public int[][] table = new int[8][8] ;
    public void initTable()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    if(j % 2 == 0) {
                        table[i][j] = 1; //black field
                    }
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if(j % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        table[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to color gridpane cells. I tried this:

```
public class GameController {

   @FXML
   private GridPane gridPane;

   @FXML
   private Pane blackPane = new Pane();

   @FXML
   private Pane whitePane = new Pane();;

   private final Game game = new Game();

   public void initGame () {
       blackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #454343;");
       whitePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fafafa;");
       System.out.println("PRESSED");
       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
               if (game.table[i][j] == 1) {
                   gridPane.add(blackPane, i, j);
               }
               if (game.table[i][j] == 0) {
                   gridPane.add(whitePane, i, j);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

When I press the button it calls the function, prints out "PRESSED", but don't changes the background color to black or white.

What might be the problem?

Comment: You can't add the same node multiple times to the scene.

Comment: And how can I solve this problem? As you see I can't get over it. 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008348/chess-table-in-javafx]

Comment: Create a new pane for each "cell". BTW you really don't need that array of `int`s. Just check `if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) { /* color pane black * /} else { /* color pane white */ }`.

Comment: I created, but I don't know how to reach them.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Now I have pane in each "cell". So how can I change their color?

Comment: Change their color before you add them? Or right after? Just call `setStyle(...)` as you do with the panes already in your code.

Comment: just wildly guessing: if you want to change the background on some user interaction with the panes, you'll need to register the appropriate handler on each pane. Might be a could idea  to work through a basic tutorial on how to use event handlers .. :) Anyway, whatever you want, you need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4):

I made a small example how you could do it. Maybe you can find the mistake in your code when analysing my example.

Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private GridPane gameFieldGridPane;

    // Choose what u need:
    private Pane[][] paneArray;
    private List<Pane> paneList;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        paneList = new ArrayList<>();
        paneArray = new Pane[8][8];
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleStartBtnClick() {
        System.out.println("PRESSED");

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                Pane pane = new Pane();
                paneList.add(pane);
                paneArray[i][j] = pane;

                String blueStyle = "-fx-background-color: blue;",
                        redStyle = "-fx-background-color: red;";

                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    if (j % 2 == 0) {
                        pane.setStyle(redStyle);
                    } else {
                        pane.setStyle(blueStyle);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (j % 2 != 0) {
                        pane.setStyle(redStyle);
                    } else {
                        pane.setStyle(blueStyle);
                    }
                }

                gameFieldGridPane.add(pane, j, i);
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleMakeBlackBtnClick() {
        changeColorToBlack(paneArray[2][2]);

        // or equivalent:
        // changeColorToBlack(paneList.get(18));
    }

    private void changeColorToBlack(Pane pane) {
        if (pane == null) return;
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
    }
}
```

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="3.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="gameFieldGridPane">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
      <Button onAction="#handleStartBtnClick" text="Start" />
      <Button onAction="#handleMakeBlackBtnClick" text="Make one Pane black" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Preview:

[image: preview]

Comment: You are welcome and yes; you can use e. g. an AnchorPane as the root layout (instead of the VBox I used).